# Use error message with numpy.testing.assert_raises()

Tags: python, unit-testing, numpy

Contrary to `np.testing.assert_equal()`, `np.testing.assert_raises(`) does not accept an `err_msg` parameter. Is there a clean way to display an error message when this assert fails?

More generally, why do some `assert_*` methods accept this parameter, while some others don't?

Answer (score 0):

These functions are implemented in `numpy/testing/utils.py`.  Studying that code may be your best option.

I see that `assert_raises` passes the task on to `nose.tools.assert_raises(*args,**kwargs)`.  So it depends on what that does.  And if I recall use of this in other modules correctly, you are usually more interested in the error message raised by the Error, as opposed to displaying your own.  Remember, `unittests` are more for your own diagnostic purposes, not as a final user-friendly tool.

`assert_equal` is a complex function that tests various kinds of objects, and builds the error message accordingly.  It may including information of the objects.

Choices in this part of the code were determined largely by what has been useful to the developers.  They are written primarily to test the `numpy` code itself.  So being systematic is not a priority.